# GD::Graph plotting different values to the ones in array

Tags: gd-graph

I am using GD:Graph to create a bandwidth graph on a webpage (Fedora 20, Apache server). I use perl to extract the bandwidth data from a MS SQL database and store the data in arrays. The bandwidth is stored in the database in bps, but in the query to extract the data it is converted to Mbps. This all work correctly as below:

```
2014-07-01T00:00,3.1405582,3.8008304,1.2683544,1.6903793
2014-07-01T01:00,2.9751012,3.1662459,1.2079006,1.595441
2014-07-01T02:00,3.2075243,3.8027289,1.2622523,1.6301193
2014-07-01T03:00,3.6902807,4.7468605,1.3457894,2.1229427
2014-07-01T04:00,6.4424162,10.802718,1.8392839,3.1497123
2014-07-01T05:00,14.592717,22.142509,3.5494912,5.7595339
2014-07-01T06:00,22.242992,25.463207,5.2702498,6.4294419
```

First column is the x values arrary, second is first y valus array, etc

However when I plot the line from these values I get a graph where the values plotted are a a factor of 20000 less

Can anybody help me as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: Can you add some code?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, it was me being silly. When I run the code natively, it was working because perl was undef'ing my arrays for me, but when I run it on webserver with all it's caching, etc in place, the arrays were not being undef'ed. The simple addition of a undef solved the problem.
Sorry to have troubled you